# PHP Undefined index - only in development environment

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not a PHP dev - sorry for a noob question - but I'm confused by behaviour of PHP code that I was given. Everything works fine in production and UAT environments, but something is wrong with handling of collections in development environment.

In a wordpress project the code like this gives an error:

```
$contact_display_2    =   $post_meta['contact_display_2'][0];
```

The error is:
Notice: Undefined index: contact_number_2 in /www/wp-content/themes/custom/standard-content.php on line 85

I am ok understanding that there is no such variable in $post_meta array and isset() function will help to solve this particular error. My question is: what needs to be changed in environment configuration so that application would work in development environment in same way as in production? Thanks

Comment: Perhaps error reporting is turned off in production and on in development? In which case, your settings are probably correct.

Comment: As above, error messages in production can be a security issue, so are suppressed. They are quite possably filling up some log files on the server though. All errors should be handled during development before pushing to production, so be prepared to write a lot of `isset()`

Comment: I think, if you change $contact_display_2    =   $post_meta['contact_display_2'][0]; to $contact_number_2    =   $post_meta['contact_number_2'][0]; that will fix the problem

Comment: But I see I was reading to fast. Why would you want to view errors in your production environment? This is a really bad practice.

Comment: I'm confused because these errors turn up everywhere across the project. This is why I thought that it might be some recent PHP release that has verbose error notifications or some "strict" error handling mode. OK, I'll do isset's if this is the way to go. thanks

Comment: Wordpress is full of notices due to bad programming (opinion). In development mode these errors are showed for developers to fix. In production they are turned off. You wouldn't want your visitors to see all kinds of errors. That doesn't mean the errors aren't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual work around when you find yourself with some code written this badly is to amend your php.ini file and turn off this parameter

```
display_errors=Off
```

This will stop the errors being shown on the browser, but they may still be logged to a file, see the `error_log = "some file in a folder"`

A better solution, if you are running your WP project in an Apache Virtual Host is to turn this parameter off from within the Virtual Hosts definition like so

```
php_flag display_errors Off
```

This way is better as it only turns this parameter off for the one badly written site and not every site that you might be developing/maintaining. This stops you writing code as badly as the the developer that wrote the site you are now stuck with.